# Taxonomy term URL to eternity

Tags: redirection, uri

What are you doing with URL's for Taxonomy terms, which tend to go in eternity, i.e.

/zen/taxonomy/term/4/615

which is identical with all

term/1 term/2 term/n etc....

They all show the same page?!

---

**Edit:**

So, yeah, people, this appears a way bigger issue with Drupal as I initially assumed...

I found a few more discussions on this topic, dated 5 and 2 years ago and without any real solution.
And the possible problem is - hundreds and thousands of duplicate content pages, strictly banned by Google and other search engines....

So here is my 2 cents:

1. My first assumption was that I could do some simple re-direct....I would take this [Match Redirect Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect), which supports Wildcard redirects and do a few redirects like this:

node/ */ * to front

taxonomy/term/ */ * to front

taxonomy/term/ */feed/ * to front

-- But the Problem now is:

- It makes impossible to Edit Nodes, which are by path....

node/*/edit

---> So I need Exclusion -> but it's not supported in module....

---

So - I am still with problem....

I don't know .htaccess regex so good to write it, I will search around and learn again....

But if there are some people who could write this for us - it would be appreciated very much...

Answer (score 1):

A taxonomy term page is reached through

```
taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term
```

In taxonomy_menu it is defined as:

```
 $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'] = array(
    'title' => 'Taxonomy term',
    'title callback' => 'taxonomy_term_title',
    'title arguments' => array(2),
    'page callback' => 'taxonomy_term_page',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'taxonomy.pages.inc',
  );
```

The page argument is set to the 2nd term counting from 0, which is %taxonomy_term.

It is therefore expecting to pass on one argument.

The page callback has this signature:

```
function taxonomy_term_page($term)
```

It also is expecting one argument (a loaded taxonomy object).

If you provide any extra arguments they are simply ignored as there is **no better fit**. However, if you look up a path such as:

```
taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit
```

then you are taken to the edit page because such a path actually exists and is the best fit. And if you look up a path such as:

```
taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit/blah/blah/blah
```

then you will be taken to the ancestor that fits best, which will be the edit page again.

It has nothing to do with taxonomy terms per se, but with the way a menu callback expects arguments.

Read more here: [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and [Wildcard, ancestors and fitness](https://www.drupal.org/node/109134)

Comment: I didn't got from all this written how to escape duplicated content penalty from Google and others. And the same thing happens not only for taxonomy, but also for nodes...

Comment: You have an incorrect idea of how search engines work. No search engine that I know of will make up arbitrary links to follow. The search engine will follow links that are on the page except if it has rel="nofollow" attribute. So how does a page like taxonomy/term/10/eternity/somemoreeternity get onto a page. Only if you put it there.

Comment: Use [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to ensure accessibility, usability and SEO

Comment: No, it's not me; I have seen how different Bots regularly scrap for non-existing pages, they got on Google; Google checks - Ohh, we see the same content by several URL's - it's a duplicate content, we ban that! For the same reason so many people put 'Nofollow' even for category/ archive etc. pages...I do Use Global Redirect, but it noway does help with those problems.